# Why is the element type here annotated as Integer and not Integer[]?

Tags: java, annotations

Let's say that `@TypeAnno` is some type annotation.

```
@TypeAnno Integer[] vec;
```

Here the element type `Integer` is annotated and not `Integer[]`. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A type annotation applies to the immediately following type component.

`Integer[]` is a compond type that consists of two parts:  `[]` is the array part and `Integer` is the element type.  It is desirable to be able to write a type annotation on each of the parts.
`@Nullable Object @NonNull []` is a non-null array of possibly-null objects.

For more information,
See the Type Annotations FAQ entries
[What is the meaning of array annotations such as @NonNull Object @Nullable []?](https://checkerframework.org/jsr308/jsr308-faq.html#array-syntax-meaning) and [I don't like array and receiver annotations.](https://checkerframework.org/jsr308/jsr308-faq.html#array-syntax).  Also
see section [Syntax of array annotations](https://checkerframework.org/jsr308/specification/java-annotation-design.html#array-syntax) in the type annotation specifiaction.  This is also addressed in the Java Language Specification (for example, section [Where Annotations May Appear](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.7.4)).